# Need to remove windows topbar in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to remove the topbar of a window (the title, icon, resize and close window buttons) without `root.overrideredirect(True)` because this method will toggle other things that I need too. Is there a different way to remove the topbar with tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove it is with `overrideredirect`.